# list to view with foreign key in JSP from DB

Tags: spring, jsp, jpa, spring-mvc

I have problem with display datasource from DB. If I want display ID (foreign key) everything working good, but I want diaplay name.

Working good and displays department ID:

```
<c:if test="${!empty contactList}">
    <table class="data">
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${contactList}" var="contact">
            <tr>
                <td>${contact.firstname}</td>
                <td>${contact.lastname}</td>
                <td>${contact.email}</td>
                <td>${contact.telephone}</td>
                <td>${contact.department.id}</td>


            <!--    <td><a href="delete/${contact.id}.html">delete</a></td>-->
            <td>
                &nbsp;<a href="updateContact.do?id=${contact.id}">Edit</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:deleteContact('deleteContact.do?id=${contact.id}');">delete</a>

            </td>

            </tr>
```

I want:

```
<td>${contact.department.name}</td>
```

controller:

```
 @RequestMapping("/showContacts")
    public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map) {

        User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String name = user.getUsername();       
        map.put("username", name);
        map.put("contact", new Contact());      
    //  map.put("department", new Department());
        map.put("contactList", contactService.listContact());

        return "showContacts";
    }
```

Entity with foreign key:

```
package pl.ivmx.contact.form;



import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import pl.ivmx.department.form.Department;

@Entity
@Table(name="CONTACTS")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="TELEPHONE")
    private int telephone;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Department_ID", nullable = false)
    private Department department;


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public int getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public void setTelephone(int telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

}
```

Second entity:

```
package pl.ivmx.department.form;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import pl.ivmx.contact.form.Contact;;

@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department implements Serializable{

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Contact> contact = new HashSet<Contact>();


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Department_ID")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "department")
    public Set<Contact> getContact() {
        return contact;
    }
    public void setContact(Set<Contact> contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }


}
```

ERROR:

FeachType.EAGER:

```
type Exception report

message javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'name' on type pl.ivmx.department.form.Department_$$_javassist_0

description The server encountered an internal error (javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'name' on type pl.ivmx.department.form.Department_$$_javassist_0) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'name' on type pl.ivmx.department.form.Department_$$_javassist_0
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)

root cause

javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'name' on type pl.ivmx.department.form.Department_$$_javassist_0
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:98)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:985)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.showContacts_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(showContacts_jsp.java:368)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.showContacts_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f2(showContacts_jsp.java:318)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.showContacts_jsp._jspService(showContacts_jsp.java:137)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)

root cause

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:132)
    org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:174)
    org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    pl.ivmx.department.form.Department_$$_javassist_0.getName(Department_$$_javassist_0.java)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:985)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.showContacts_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(showContacts_jsp.java:368)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.showContacts_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f2(showContacts_jsp.java:318)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.showContacts_jsp._jspService(showContacts_jsp.java:137)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

Comment: `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/pages/showContacts.jsp at line 38

35:      <td>${contact.lastname}</td>
36:      <td>${contact.email}</td>
37:      <td>${contact.telephone}</td>
38:      <td>${contact.department.name}</td>
39: 
40:    


Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)`

Comment: can you update your question with the full stacktrace?

Comment: I want display department name in table `<td>${contact.department.name}</td>`. Now i can diasplay only ID.   `<td>${contact.department.id}</td>`

Comment: Yes I Know but I need to know what is the error to be able to help you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to access property of a bean that is being fetched lazily. When the view is rendered, the session with the database is already closed. To be able to do this, set the fetch type to `FetchType.EAGER` or use the `Open Session In View Pattern` if you want to keep it to `LAZY`

If you use Hibernate as your JPA provider, you might consider reading this [example](http://blog.cloudmate.pl/2010/09/hibernates-open-session-in-view-in.html) to see how to implement the Open Session in view pattern with `Spring MVC` and `Hibernate`.

Comment: Or use a query that fetches the the contacts with their department.

Comment: This is also a viable solution

Comment: I change `FetchType.LAZY` to `FetchType.EAGER`  and problem its the same.

Comment: i change ERROR Stacktrace when I use FeachType.EAGER

Comment: You changed it on the contact entity for the department property?

Comment: `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "department")
 public Set<Contact> getContact() {
  return contact;
 }`

Comment: You need to change it on the Contact Object :     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Department_ID", nullable = false)
    private Department department;